# Jest run a single test to get Authentication token before running all tests specified across multiple.test.ts files

Tags: jestjs

I am using Jest to automate the testing of a specific API that involves multiple endpoints. The way I have structured my framework is that I have a specific request spec class and test.ts file (i.e. test suite) for each of the endpoints. The calls to these endpoints are authenticated with a token. So in each of the .test.ts test suite files I am using the below beforeAll hook to get the token that is used in each of my tests within the test suite.

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    pricesRequest = new PricesRequestSpec();
    tokenRequest = new TokenRequestSpec();
    token = await tokenRequest.postTokenRequest();
});
```

This is fine in that I am only retrieving and using 1 token for all tests in a test suite rather than for each test, however as I have 6 endpoints with the tests for each of these in 6 separate .test.ts files I am making 6 requests for a new token when I really only need to make 1. Is there a way to run the request to retrieve the token before executing any of the testsuites so that I can make just 1 call for get token rather than multiple i.e. using some globalConfig. I know I could get around this by having all tests in the single test.ts testSuite file but for readability purposes I want to keep these in separate folders.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to do this. I created a script globalSetup.ts in which I make the call to get the token and set this as an env variable..

```
export default async () => {
    let tokenRequest = new TokenRequestSpec();
    const token = await tokenRequest.postTokenRequest();
    process.env.bearerToken = token;
}
```

I point to this file in my jest.config.ts for the param...

```
globalSetup: './jestGlobalSetup.ts'
```

I can then access this environment varaibles within all my test scripts e.g.

```
    it('returns status 200 and expected response', async () => {
        const response = await pricesRequest.getPricesRequest(process.env.bearerToken, queryParams);
        pricesRequest.validateSuccessfulResponse(response);
    })
```